# Javascript and Parsed JSON - Child node's ['@attributes'].type returns undefined

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array, attributes

I've parsed a legitimate JSON object and I'm walking through the multidimensional array to first find the year based on a function argument and then the month within that year.

My for loops are nested:

```
    for (year in yearsData) {
        //If we've found the correct year...
        if (yearsData[year]['@attributes'].name == yearToGet) {

        //...walk through that year's child months
        for (month in yearsData[year]) {

            //This works!
            console.log(yearsData[year][month]);

            //This also works!
            console.log(yearsData[year][month]['@attributes']);

            //This does not work! ..but this is what I need!
            console.log(yearsData[year][month]['@attributes'].name);
        }       
   }
```

---

I can track the object in Firebug's console (with valid output) all the way up to

> console.log(yearsData[year][month]['@attributes']);

But the instant I add the type at the end (.name):

> yearsData[year][month]['@attributes'] is undefined.

console.log(yearsData[year][month]); returns the valid object, and I can *see* the valid @attributes listed.

I've checked the spelling multiple times; I've changed the name of the attribute to other things in case it was somehow conflicting with year's attributes..but I got nothin'.

What simple thing am I missing?

The JSON:

```
{
"year": [
    {
        "@attributes": {
            "name": "2013"
        },
        "month": {
            "@attributes": {
                "name": "January"
            },
            "winner": "None!",
            "theme": "Nobody!"
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: you should include a portion of your JSON that's relevant to the question

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(yearsData[year][month]);` ?

Comment: I've edited the above to include the JSON. The output of console.log(yearsData[year][month]);, within that for (month in..) loop is the month data, including attributes and children.

Comment: My reproduction of your code works correctly in Chrome 10 and IE 10: http://jsfiddle.net/BWYMf/. Does the fiddle version work for you too?

Comment: I tested the fiddle version with a C/P, and now it returns the ['@attributes'] of the year when I call for the [month]['@attributes']...I guess that's progress.

I *am* using WAMP to test locally- could this be a cause for the weirdness?

Answer (score 0):

Think about using jQuery.grep or jQuery.each to work efficiently on object iteration and analysis. It can help a lot.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have that option for this particular project.

Answer (score 0):

After some more brainbashing, it turned out to be a super derp. I was using month the variable rather than the string 'month' that would ID it.

I'd need to use: console.log(yearsData[year]['month']['@attributes'].name);

To get it. Whoo.